# Firebase addDoc not writing data to Firestore

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to write some data to my Firestore database. I've been following Firebase docs but for some reason nothing is being written to my database. I'm not receiving any console errors but there are no new docs being written. I've also tried using setDoc, but no luck with that either.

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.8/firebase-app.js";
import { getFirestore, doc, setDoc, addDoc, collection } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.8/firebase-firestore.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
   ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();

var submitPost = document.getElementById("submitPost");

submitPost.addEventListener("click", writeToDB, false);

async function writeToDB() {
   console.log("HIT ME")
   const newDoc = await addDoc(collection(db, 'posts'), {
       test: 'TEST',
       please: 'WORK',
   });
};
```

Here is my Firestore console after running the function, it does not contain any new documents, only one I have already made manually:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

when you use async/await syntax instead .then() make sure to
put a try/catch around your await to capture any possible error in your Promise.

```
  async function writeToDB() {
    console.log("HIT ME")
    try {
      const newDoc = await addDoc(collection(db, 'posts'), {
        test: 'TEST',
        please: 'WORK', });

    } catch(err) {
      console.error("writeToDB failed. reason :", err)
    }
  };
```

if you don't enclose it in try/catch any promise fail will be silent. And it would be equivalent of not having .catch() after .then()

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm new to async functions so that's good info. However, I reran the function with this updated code and still nothing. All I see in the console is the "hit me" statement.

Comment: let's add another line await operation to see if it was successful (see below)

Comment: console.log("Document written with ID: ", newDoc.id);

Comment: if it is successful then maybe you are writing into a wrong firebase project :)

Comment: Just added that statement inside the try block and no luck - still just the hit me. So the try isn't being hit but it's also not catching anything? Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: the best way is to debug it in chrome dev tool if running in browser.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to initialize your Firestore to obtain a reference to the service:

Your existing code:

```
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();
```

Should be:

```
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
```

For reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize